# How can I order a list by 2 properties from my class

Tags: c#, list, class

For this application I want to put animals into a train. There are 6 types of animals. Large carnivore, medium carnivore small carnivore, Large herbivore, medium herbivore, and a small herbivore. I want to put them into my list in that exact order. How do I do this?

This is my animal class:

public bool carnivore;

```
 public Size size;

    public Animal(bool carnivore, Enum size)
    {
        this.carnivore = carnivore;
        this.size = (Size) size;
    }
```

This is the class where I want to order them:

```
public List<Animal> Animals = new List<Animal>();

        public List<Wagon> Wagons = new List<Wagon>();

        public void Arrange()
        {
            Wagon w = new Wagon();
            Wagons.Add(w);
            foreach (Animal animal in Animals.ToList())
            {
                foreach (Wagon wagon in Wagons.ToList())
                {
                    if (wagon.addAnimal(animal))
                    {
                        wagon.addAnimal(animal);
                        Animals.Remove(animal);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Wagon wag = new Wagon();
                        wag.addAnimal(animal);
                        Animals.Remove(animal);
                        Wagons.Add(wag);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the enum:

```
public enum Size
    {
        Small = 1,
        Medium = 3,
        Large = 5
    }
```

I've found some order by and then by things, but they don't seem to work. I'm sorry if I overlooked a question that looks like mine.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does it mean `they dont seem to work.`? What issue you see with that approach? Can you share the enum Size? Also share the code which used Order By

Comment: please post the declaration of the enum. Actually simply order the values in your enum in the order that you want the animals to be. Then it should work. Dont't forget to specify ascending or descending when calling order by

Comment: Is the order important at all or do you just want to _separate_ the animals into 6 wagons? So actually a `GroupBy` at first would be a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the namespace `System.Linq` which contains very useful extension methods to handle Lists and `IEnumerables<T>` in general.

To sort as you desired, you can use this:

```
Animals.OrderBy(a => a.carnivore).ThenBy(a => a.size);
```

Comment: this depends strongly on the declaration of the enum. The order will differ if it is not correctly declared

Comment: It should be `OrderByDescending(a => a.carnivore)` and the enum could be tricky. If is defined in this order: Large, Medium, Small, then you are fine. If it is defined in this order: Small, Medium, Large, you can use `ThenByDescending` again. If it is any other order you are going to have to jump through some hoops.

Comment: @MongZhu Of course, assuming that the enum is layed out in order with their corresponding integer values.

Answer (score 0):

To separate your animals into 6 wagons by carnivority and size, you can use LINQ's `GroupBy`:

```
public void Arrange()
{
    Wagons.AddRange(
            Animals.GroupBy(animal => new {animal.carnivore, animal.size})
                   .Select(g => 
                       {
                           Wagon wagon = new Wagon();
                           foreach(Animal animal in g)
                               wagon.addAnimal(animal);
                           return wagon;
                       }));
}
```

You can of course sort the groups before projecting into wagons:

```
public void Arrange()
{
    var groupedAnimals = Animals.GroupBy(animal => new {animal.carnivore, animal.size});
    var orderedGroups = groupedAnimals.OrderBy(g => g.carnivore).ThenBy(g => g.size);

    Wagons.AddRange(orderedGroups.Select(g => 
                       {
                           Wagon wagon = new Wagon();
                           foreach(Animal animal in g)
                               wagon.addAnimal(animal);
                           return wagon;
                       }));
}
```

But as others mentioned the resulting order now depends on the declaration of the `size` enum.